# Null Pointer Exception on Alert Dialog show, only on Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-6.0-marshmallow, findviewbyid, numberpicker

I have a strange problem when I try to open `Alert Dialog` with `Number Picker` in it. It should be called after I press a `button` with `listener` set to that:

```
private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImagesActivity.this);
            AlertDialog dialog;
            final NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(ImagesActivity.this);
            np.setMinValue(1);
            np.setMaxValue(dataModel.getPagesNumber());
            np.setValue(currentPage);
            builder.setView(np);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.jump_title);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.jump_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(np.getValue() - 1);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.jump_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

**ImagesActivity** is class, where `ButtonClickListener` is placed. It shows `ViewPager`, which should be scrolled into page selected using `NumberPicker`.

It works fine on my older phones, but when I try to launch it on `Android` 6 I get that message **error**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:489)
>         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
>         at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
>         at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
>         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
>         at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
>         at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2244)
>         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
>         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Do you know what can it be caused by? And how can I fix it up?

Comment: I don't have setupView() code, I think it's provided by Android Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem.

I had to change

```
import android.app.alertdialog;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.alertdialog;
```

Probably there was some type of change since Marshmallow version, which causes problem when we're not carefull enough about using standard/support versions of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

This means you messed up alertDialogStyle - it reads the layout res id from there and if it doesn't load the correct layout, it will NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the NumberPicker inside a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout and then setting the dialog view to that LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Edit:
You can try to have your NumberPicker inside a layout xml and inflate it, and use this at the setView method call

Comment: Unforunately, it didn't help. I still get the error message.

Comment: If you comment out the builder.setView(np); you still have the error?

Comment: Please check my edit to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: No, it didn't help either. I also get this error with builder.setView(np); line commented